# How can I implement onCreateOptionsMenu on my bottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

Hi I wouldike to know when I click on my bottomnavigationView how to display my search toolbar ?

```
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           switch (item.getItemId()) {

               case R.id.navigation_home:

                   return true;

               case R.id.navigation_loope:
```

toolbar_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:title="Search"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

Bottom_nav_view.xml

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_loope"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_loope"
        android:title="@string/title_loope"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_take_photo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_take_photo"
        android:title="@string/title_take_photo" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_public"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_public"
        android:title="@string/title_public" />

</menu>
```

I can't actually use `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)` I don't know how to implement it for doing the same result when i click on my loope (R.id.navigation_loope)

EDIT : Bottom_nav_view it's for my bottom bar and toolbar_menu for my topbar. If I click on the item navigation_loop, I wouldike to show the search bar on the top.

Comment: could you show us the layout xml?

Comment: Sure @lvl4fi4 I will edit that.